# search all fields in django

Tags: django, search, model

I have 5 tables in my model.py and I want so search all of them with one string, i.e compare all fields in a tables with one search string. But I am nt able to find how I can do that.

```
class Person(models.Model):

    mail=models.EmailField()
    firstName=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastName=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phoneNumber=PhoneNumberField()
    streetAdress=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    zipcode=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=200,default="Göteborg")
    country=models.CharField(max_length=200,default="Sweden")

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.firstName,self.lastName)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('firstName','lastName')

class Role(models.Model):

    role=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    person=models.ManyToManyField(Person)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.role

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('role',)

class Name(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    role=models.ForeignKey(Role,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

class Address(models.Model):

    name=models.ForeignKey(Name,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    venue=models.CharField(max_length=200,default="Company AB")
    street=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mail=models.EmailField()
    phone=PhoneNumberField(default="")

    def __str__(self):
         return str(self.venue)

    # def __str__(self):
    #     return str(self.phone)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "addreses"

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

class Date(models.Model):

    date=models.DateField()
    location=models.ManyToManyField(Address)

    def __str__(self):
         return str(self.date)
```

and doing search is done only in the name field:

```
class Search(ListView):
    print("class Search")
    model=Person
    template_name='artdb/search.html'
    context_object_name='ans'
#    Pdb().set_trace()

    def get_queryset(self):
        q=self.request.GET.get('seastr')
        if q:
            qans=firstName__icontains=q
            return Person.objects.filter(firstName__icontains=q)
        else:
            return Person.objects.all()  # SELECT ... WHERE headline ILIKE '%Lennon%';


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['seastr'] = self.request.GET.get('seastr')
        return context
```

is there anyway to do a search for all tables and fields? like a wildcard search? is there any equivalent wildcard search to __icontains?